# How to insert time in SQl Server 2005?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I am creating windows application .In this I have to subtract two dates .I subtract it successfully  ,I used TimeSpan to get subtracted value.But when I insert it in SQl Server 2005 db, it inserted with starting date i.e. 1/1/1900 and the calculated difference

which format should I use to insert Time only?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the date you want to insert?
remember time span is not a date, is just a range of dates.

Answer (score 1):

sql date format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`
for example: `2010-05-07 09:59:59`

Comment: That format isn't 100% safe for all regional settings. Safe formats are "YYYYMMDD" and "YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss" (where 'T' is literally the letter T between the date and time components), e.g. for your example, '2010-05-07T09:59:59'

Answer (score 1):

If you insert just the timespan, it will be interpreted as the time past midnight on 1/1/1900. Perhaps you can convert the timespan to seconds (.`TotalSeconds`, maybe?) and then store that as an INT to get what you're looking for.